# Inverted question mark, plus its gender

Tags: gender, phrases

I have found online how to say "inverted question mark" in Italian. It should be: "invertita interrogativo".

May I ask what is its grammatical gender? If it masculine or feminine?

EDIT: Is it actually correct? Shouldn't it be "punto interrogativo invertito"?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the symbol “¿”?

Comment: @DaG: I think it's that symbol: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_question_and_exclamation_marks.

Comment: yes I mean exactly that symbol, image http://www.iocresco.it/images/phocagallery/PECS/Simboli/Accesso%20al%20computer/Punteggiatura/thumbs/phoca_thumb_l_upside%20down%20question%20mark.jpg

Answer (score 9):

It's an error. You could say either:

- punto interrogativo invertito: [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punto_interrogativo#Il_punto_interrogativo_in_spagnolo), [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-2662/6jbs66vis/index.html)
- punto interrogativo rovesciato/rovescio: [here](http://www.inspagnolo.it/2012/11/il-punto-di-domanda-rovesciato.html) and [here](http://it.wikihow.com/Fare-un-Punto-Interrogativo-Rovesciato).
- punto interrogativo capovolto: [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punto_esclarrogativo#Il_punto_esclarrogativo_in_spagnolo).

The second seems to provide more results on search engines.
Gender is always masculine (because "punto" is masculine).

Comment: Anche *rovescio*. Se la domanda è in inglese, dovrebbe esserlo anche la risposta.

Comment: Penso che @egreg abbia ragione: potresti aggiungere una traduzione della risposta all'inglese?

Comment: scusate, non ci ho fatto caso... ho fornito la traduzione

Comment: Sembra abbastanza usato (e a me suona più naturale) anche “punto interrogativo capovolto”.

Comment: Google translate is a free service. It's certainly better than nothing, and IME one at least gets the gist of the meaning of a passage. But before criticizing, why not check your facts? Google translates "inverted question mark" as "invertito punto interrogativo".

Comment: @andy256: «Google translates "inverted question mark" as "invertito punto interrogativo"»: thanks for verifying. Be aware that it is quite as bad as “invertita interrogativo”.

Comment: @andy256 as DaG already noted, GT provides a non-grammatical translation: while it's true that you can use it to get the gist of the meaning, you can't absolutely use it to check how to translate something: in other words, you can use to understand a bit FROM a language you don't know well, but you can NOT use it to PRODUCE in a language you don't know well. I wasn't criticizing, BTW, just telling a student to not trust automatic translators..